# Animate along bezierCurveTo or quadraticCurveTo

Tags: javascript, canvas

Is there a built-in way in javascript to animate an object (an image for example) along a path you've drawn using bezierCurveTo or quadraticCurveTo? What I'm trying to do is precisely animate the trajectory and landing spot of a ball if that helps.

Comment: If it's a ball affected by gravity, and that's why you're using the curve, it's probably easier to model the gravity than to have it follow an arbitrary path.

Comment: Thanks Beska. The problem I'm having is getting the ball to land in a specified spot. I'm sure there's math to do this but just don't know what that is or where to look.

Comment: Hmm.  Yep.  There's definitely math for it.  I could easily come up with a quadradic that would satisfy the "land at point x" requirement, but coming up with a gravity formula is a bit trickier.  It might be easier just to guess a few times.  Maybe by assuming it starts at the ground, and launches itself up with an initial y velocity Y, you could play around with various gravity values until it reaches the height you want.  Then you could mess with the x velocity X until it reaches the x,y point you want at its apex.  Then it's just a matter of starting it at x,y, with velocity -X, 0.

Comment: Of course, if you're going to do that, it's probably just as easy to start it at the spot x,y, adjust gravity (which is the only factor that will affect Y) until it looks good (the velocity from start to finish when it hits the ground seems reasonable), and adjust then adjust the X velocity until it lands in the right spot.

Comment: Gravity is probably a bit quicker to calculate as well...plotting along a curve probably involves solving some kind of parametric equation multiple times.  Gravity is quick by comparision, since you just add a some value to your y velocity each cycle, and then move a standard delta amount * velocity.

Comment: Yeah I think you're right and the latter might be my best bet. Also, I found this: http://osteele.com/archives/2006/02/javascript-beziers while searching and the first example shows an object animating along a path so I'm wondering if there's a way to go that route too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a built-in way in javascript

No, sorry. Really that's the short answer here. There's not, at least not in canvas.

There *is* a way to animate along a path in SVG though. In fact you could animate along SVG and capture all of the x,y points as you go to use in Canvas, though that's probably really inefficient.

The other way is to do the math to bisect (split) a bezier curve, which coincidentally gets you the midpoint of that curve. Then bisect the two smaller curves. Do this over and over and eventually you get a list of midpoints that you can use to plot the trajectory of the object you want to animate.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is kind of late, but I think this might be what you're looking for.

Example: http://joelb.me/scrollpath/
Git: https://github.com/JoelBesada/scrollpath

Answer (score 1):

There is, though browser support is still spotty: you can use dashed lines.

So if you have a draw function:

```
function draw() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(20,20);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(100,100,30,90);
}
```

you can set up your animation thus:

```
var start = null;
var duration = 1000;
var length = 150; // I'm guessing here, but you can calculate it

function step(timestamp) {
  if(start === null) { start = timestamp; } 
  canvas.width = canvas.width;
  var progress = Math.min((timestamp - start)/duration,1);
  ctx.setLineDash([0,length,3,0]);
  ctx.lineWidth = 3;
  ctx.lineDashOffset = progress * length;
  draw();
  ctx.stroke();
  if(progress < 1) {
    requestAnimationFrame(step);
  }
}
requestAnimationFrame(step);
```

You've just got to make sure the initial dash space is longer than your entire line, and then animate the offset along so the single short dash (your 'dot') slides out along your path. You can round it with `lineCap`. Working demo: http://jsbin.com/UFOTavoX/1

Support for `setLineDash` and `lineDashOffset` is not universal. http://www.rgraph.net/blog/2013/january/html5-canvas-dashed-lines.html talks more about it.